# Going to any SE chat site on mobile browser loads softwareengineering.SE chat

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

Whenever I try to load the RPG.SE chat site from the mobile site for the main RPG.SE on android chrome, it loads https://chat.stackexchange.com/, which displays as the desktop site and only displays Software Engineering.SE chat rooms.

How can I get to other chat sites on mobile?

Screens:

[image: Loading chat.stackexchange.com on android chrome on OnePlus2]
[image: Displays as desktop site for softwareengineering.SE rooms only, despite settings, android chrome on OnePlus2]

Comment: No repro, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @shadowwizard included in edits

Comment: Thanks. While I still can't reproduce, when going to mobile theme, I see Stack Overflow rooms, which is even weirder. Something is borked, that's for sure